# Lagging/Stuttering video on Local HDD

Tags: pi-2, kodi, hard-drive, openelec

I have an RPI-2-B with OpenELEC/Kodi installed. I am currently uncertain of the version, but I will get right back with that as soon as I can. I recently moved a series to one of my HDD's directly connected to my RPI via USB.

I have 2 HDD's directly connected to my RPI, and all movies and most series play just fine. For some reason when I try to play an episode of the series in question the video goes all bad and stutters, while it seems the audio plays back just fine. The episodes are all MKV-files and of a size of 200 MB. When I check the video quality in the Kodi GUI, they are all classified as HD, and as far as I remember they should all be 1080p, so that makes sense.

I am planning on trying to update to the newest version, 6.x, as I believe I am on 4 or 5, but I will check up on that and perform an update as soon as I get time.

Does anyone here know what this error could be caused by?

I have experienced this before, with a different series, which I was then forced to find in a lower quality, but that's not always possible. I am able to play most 1080p movies and other series as well without problems,  it's just this one season that is causing me troubles.

## EDIT1:

I checked my version and it seems I am running 6.0.3.

## EDIT2:

I have performed a manual update to 6.95.3. Will check if performance has improved once I've cleaned up my library, which might take some time.

Comment: Do you have other high resolution mkv files that play back correctly?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have. I will check that out though and report back once I've done that

Comment: Yes. I have other that works just right.

Answer (score 1):

After updating from 6.0.3 to 6.95.3 and cleaning my library my problem was solved. The episodes are playing flawlessly now.